# Cron error: LogicException : Render context is empty

Tags: views, 8, cron

In a custom module (sel), I have this code:

```
function sel_cron()
{
  $accountSwitcher = Drupal::service('account_switcher');
  $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $accountSwitcher->switchTo($account);

  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('service_category');
  $dLastExtractionDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime("- 1 week", strtotime(\Drupal::state()->get('sel.NextEmailForNewServices'))));
  $view = views_embed_view('sel_services', 'embed_2', $dLastExtractionDate);
  $view = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($view);   <--------------------- problem here

  $accountSwitcher->switchBack();
}
```

The expected result of the view is a table but when the result is empty (because of the value of the contextual filter), an unfiltered text ("Nothing to display today. Too bad!") should be displayed instead.
But in this case, I get this error logged:

> LogicException: Render context is empty, because render() was called
>   outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use
>   renderPlain()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead. in
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (line 243 of
>   /Users/efalzon/Sites/JdP8/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php).

How to fix that?

Comment: That's a cron job though - where are you expecting it to render?

Comment: The result of the view becomes the body of an email sent with `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail(some params);`

Comment: Oh ok, in that case you want to use `renderPlain`, not `render`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292171/what-is-the-difference-between-renderplain-and-renderroot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$view = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($view);
```

instead of

```
$view = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($view);
```

was the solution!
Thanks to @Clive