# How to render HTML output in hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

Upon node save, I want to take the value of a text field that uses a custom input filter and save the HTML-ified final version (what the input filter renders) in a second field.

I have two text fields:

- Field **text_main** (which is never actually displayed, avoiding the performance penalty of rendering the field)
- Field **text_main_display** (which is displayed publicly)

The field **text_main** uses a [custom input filter](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/creating-a-custom-filter-in-drupal-8) that is very slow to run.  So, I want to get the rendered output of the field after running the input filter and save it to the field **text_main_display**.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()
 */
function MYMODULE_node_presave(NodeInterface $entity) {
  switch ($entity->getType()) {
    case 'custom_page':
      $processedResult = $entity->get('field_text_main')->view('custom_display');
      // $processedResult is now a render array. How do I render this to HTML?
      $entity->set('field_text_main_display', $processedResult);
      break;
  }
}
```

Reference: [This post on how to render Drupal 8 fields](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-8-fields-right-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hooks which are not executed in a render context use renderPlain(), see [Cron error: LogicException : Render context is empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293201/cron-error-logicexception-render-context-is-empty)

```
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($processedResult);
```

Caveat: Text filters can bubble up metadata which you ignore by storing only the HTML. For a custom text filter this might be OK when you know it doesn't depend on cache metadata and attachments, but don't use this as a general approach. This can have security implications, like revealing data to non-authorized users.