# Update the text format and process the body field of existing nodes programmatically

Tags: nodes, hooks, drush

I am trying to resave a number of nodes to apply the text format changes to the body field. I’ve written a drush command to do this. The command does update the text format, but the text in the body field remains unprocessed.

```
public function saveNode() {
    $result = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
    foreach ($result as $node) {
        $node->save();
      }
    }
  }
```

If I manually edit and save the node the text in the body field is correctly processed, but not when saved programmatically.

Notes:
By "unprocessed" I mean the body field is still showing faulty HTML. If I manually edit and save the node the faulty HTML is fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "unprocessed"?  Text field value is not processed until the field is rendered, so if you are doing something unusual like saving rendered field output, you need to render the field first.

Comment: Changing the text format won't update the text in the database, if that's what you're expecting. Filters are applied on render, not for storage

Comment: For an example of applying the renderer, see this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/293716/5147

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure that I understand what you code is doing.
Something like this might work.

```
$html_format = 'full_html';
$type = 'some_type';

$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('node')
            ->loadByProperties([
                'type' => $type,
            ]);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {

    $current_body_data = $node->get('body')->getValue();
    $current_body_value = $current_body_data[0]['value'];

    $new_body_data = [
            'value' => $current_body_value,
            'format' => $html_format,
        ];
    
    $node->set('body', $new_body_data);

    $node->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions give errors in drupal 9 / 10, If you want to achieve this then do the following in a update hook.

```
$node->set('body', $node->get('body')->value); // Set the new value or existing value here.
$node->body->format = 'full_html'; // Set your format here.
$node->save(); // Save the node.
```